Check for at least 1 digit and 1 letter within the first n characters
I have to check if there are numbers and letters in the first 5 characters of an order number from a customer.
There must always be at least 1 letter and at least 1 number.
Internal information that are not relevant for the check can be appended after the order number. Therefore, only the first 5 characters need to be checked.
The position of the characters is different each time.
So far I have
\A\w{5}

But how can I check that there is always 1 letter and 1 number?
String examples:
Correct: A1Aaa, 1AAAA, 1111a, A1A1A. AAA123!A
Incorrect: aaAAA, 11111, A AAA, A1, AA!1AA !A11
There are different requirements for checking the order numbers for each customer. I want to save the regex expression in the DB to dynamically load and check the order numbers for each customer with their regex expression.
This above is the requirement of one customer. Another one has e.g. 7 characters with only numbers.
It would be great if someone here could help me!

You may not always be able to merge all requirements into a single Regex (and I certainly would not recommend to even try that). You may even need to have a "whitelist" and "blacklist" of regexes. That will make implementing the system more complex but implementing the requirements per customer waaaaayyyyy easier.

Does it have to be a regex? Regex are usually kind of hard to maintain. I would just use normal built-in functions. ("A1Aaa".Any(char.IsDigit) && "A1Aaa".Any(char.IsLetter)).

^^ Why do I suggest this? - I actually had to do exactly this some years ago and clients would have crazy requirements like "classes" of order numbers. Like "If it starts with A then the next 5 chars must ... and the last one is always a 0, if it start with O, P, K or a Digit except 5, then ..."

@ChrisFromTheBlock Problem is, OP is supposed to persist those rules in (what I assume is) a SQL DB ... with regex you simply save a string. With functions or expressions it gets somewhat harder to do.

Splitting the regexes can also make each single regex perform way faster and you can sort the ones that are most frequent hits to be checked first. So you have a statistical performance gain.

^(?=.[A-Za-z])(?=.\d)[A-Za-z\d]{5}.Also using a giant regex for all customers is dangerous in the long run.Implementing per customer as Fildor mentioned should work.

@AmadeuszLiu I even suggested to have several regex per customer :D and on top to have positive ones and then excluding ones, too. So it is easier to throw out false positives.

@Ebert Nevermind the downvotes. I guess even mentioning "Regex" is triggering today. IMHO, you sufficiently layed down the reason why it seems to be the right tool for you. (At least for now)

I used to have everything in If queries. If a new customer was added, I always had to change the source code.
The administrative effort was a disaster.
This is now the most complex check. If it gets more difficult, I can also create several columns for the regex. I will think about that :D

You can use
^(?=\w{0,4}\p{L})(?=\w{0,4}\d)\w{5}

See the regex demo.
Details:

^ - start of a string
(?=\w{0,4}\p{L}) - right after, there should be 0 to 4 word chars followed with a letter
(?=\w{0,4}\d) - an there must be a digit within the first 5 word chars, too
\w{5} - then match and consume 5 word chars.


To check for 5 letters or digits but disallow 5 of each only:
\A(?!\d{5}|\D{5})[^\W_]{5}

See this demo at regex101 (I used ^ instead of \A for multilie showcase)
\w stands for word character. Upper \D is the negation of lower \d which is a short for digit. The underscore is part of \w, that's why I subtracted it in [^\W_]. Just attach .* for full matches.
